# Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'id<ChartboostDelegate>' with an lvalue of type 'AppController *'

Tags: ios, xcode, chartboost

Can you check this for me...

[code error - click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzS6j.png)

i am not allowed to add image screenshots yet.

Can you tell me how to sort this out?

I want to integrate chartboost ads, but this error is killing me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The object you passing During initialisation should conform the ChartboostDelegate otherwise you will get this error. Check you are passing `self` , but your `self` not conforming `ChartboostDelegate`